# Cannot connect to h20 in R using h2o.init()

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to connect to h20 for the first time in R Studio with the following command:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

R Versions 2.3.2 and h20 version 3.10.2.2. Any idea on how to fix this so I can connect?

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
running command ''/usr/bin/java' -version 2>&1' had status 1
Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /var/folders/w7/vpssy9010lg4xxlwkg5f2zwm0000gn/T//RtmpZhyGXB/h2o_chrisstroud_started_from_r.out
    /var/folders/w7/vpssy9010lg4xxlwkg5f2zwm0000gn/T//RtmpZhyGXB/h2o_chrisstroud_started_from_r.err

No Java runtime present, requesting install.

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................ 
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused
[1] 7
 Show Traceback
Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
```

Comment: Try to run R Studio in root (super user) mode.

Comment: Just installed the SDK and it fixed it.

Comment: Go through proper installation guide of H2O. https://github.com/chauhansaurabhb/Analysis-of-H2O-vs-SparkMLlib/blob/master/Installation_Guide.pdf

Comment: "R Versions 2.3.2" seriously? That's ancient.

Answer (score 3):

If you have proxy enabled, it won't work.

```
Sys.setenv(https_proxy="") 
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="") 
Sys.setenv(http_proxy_user="") 
Sys.setenv(https_proxy_user="")
```

fixed it for me.